# Does the Xbox 360's 'Auto Shut Off' Feature Wait for Downloads to Finish?

Tags: xbox-360

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory.  The newest version of Xbox 360 firmware comes with a feature that automatically shuts down your Xbox after a period of inactivity, which you can set yourself.  If I'm downloading something big enough that it takes longer than my shut-off time, will the Xbox wait until it's done before powering down?

Comment: There's a system setting that will cause the Xbox to stay on (even if you power it off with the power switch) to continue a download.  I think it's called "Background Downloading"  With that on, I'm fairly certain the answer is yes.  With it off I'm not so sure.  More testing would be required...

Comment: I am pretty sure @agent86 is right. I was downloading some demos on a super slow internet connection (about 4GB worth) and I left for the night, turning off the Xbox on my way out with only one of the downloads half completed.  When I turned it on the next day, all of the demos were ready to play.  I wasn't even aware of that setting (it was my roommates Xbox), but I'm assuming that's how it happened now.

Comment: @turboSwag but you actively turned it off, right?  I guess it doesn't really matter if it's on or off if I'm going to be away from it, as long as it's downloading.  But I'd still like to know about the *automatic* shutoff.

Comment: I'm not sure actually, I forgot about it, but my roommate who owned the Xbox might have turned it off.  This was also before the automatic shutoff feature possibly (around August 2012), if it is recent as you stated.  I would assume it works the same though, if anything more likely to work with automatic shutoff than manual shutoff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 6 hour turn off won't stop downloads if you have "background downloads" turned on. This is accessed via the normal 360 settings on the right most "screen".

If its downloading the power light will continue to flash after you've powered the console off. Sometimes it might take a minute or two before it kicks into this mode after being powered off - I'm not sure why but my 360 does at least.

Comment: Oh, so it will still auto-shut off, but continue to download until it's done?  That's handy.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does. If you turn it off or if it turns off automatically it will work. I was downloading GTA 5 and I fell asleep with the Xbox on and woke up with it off and it was ready to play :) Hope I helped.

Comment: Hi nick hon, and welcome to Arqade. I've suggested an edit to your answer that adds capital letters and punctuation, and expands things like "u" to whole words. You'll probably find that writing in good English makes things much more likely to be upvoted here.